# Can I retrieve "unlikes" from the Facebook API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there any way I can get a Facebook user's unlikes?

I can get a users likes by using `/{user}/likes`.

But is there any way I can see what likes the user has removed from that list? Or is there any other way to track 'unlikes'?

Comment: You shouldn't care about people that don't like you.

Answer (score 2):

There's no API call you can make that will give you a list of what a user previously liked, but now does not.